# Expected a spy, but got BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, karma-coverage

I am trying to implement a test (1) for this function (2).
My purpose is to check if the call componentsOffsetService on scroll.
I get the message Error: Expected a spy, but got BehaviorSubject. Any ideas?

(1)

```
    it('should call componentsOffsetService on scroll', () => {
    spyOn(componentsOffsetService.onScroll, 'next');
    const container = fixture.debugElement.query( By.css('.main-container'));
    container.nativeElement.scroll();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(componentsOffsetService.onScroll).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

(2)

```
public onScroll(event): void {
    this.componentsOffsetService.onScroll.next(event.target.scrollTop);
  }
```

(3) onScroll in componentsOffsetService

```
public onScroll = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code, I can see a mistake that you have set spy on `next` as

```
 spyOn(componentsOffsetService.onScroll, 'next');
```

but you are checking on `onScroll`

```
  expect(componentsOffsetService.onScroll).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

change expect as below:

```
  expect(componentsOffsetService.onScroll.next).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Comment: If I make expect(componentsOffsetService.onScroll.next).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) I've got err Expected a spy, but got Function.

Comment: @Анна: Can you please share the component code and also the test code where you have created `componentsOffsetService` in `spec` file . Its hard to provide more answer without these code

Comment: I add spec file

Comment: @Анна: I mean `TestBed` part as well